# Access MongoDB Cursor in two different request cycles

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

i'm currently searching for a solution to save the mongodb cursor (after a find()) to access it between two http requests. My environment is JAVA Spring MVC and mongodb (Spring Data) so i have all of its powerfull functionality. Unfortunately i didn't find any documentation/tutorial which solves my problem:

A client requests the first 20 results in his first request and the following 20 in his second request. Instead of querying mongo again i want to access the previously generated cursor because documents changed during time and i want to have the initial order of them. Is there any way how to do it?

Help is very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try to iterate through the `Cursor` and add everything to a `SortedMap`. Then you can query the `SortedMap` as many times as you want. You can have the `SortedMap` sort it by natural order or you can use a `Comparator` to have it sorted any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Some drivers support lazy operations on cursors called `getMore`. This will reuse your cursor ID to retrieve more data.

Unless if you strictly ask, your cursor will not do snapshots, causing strange behaviors in case of a new document get inserted or deleted (like see the same doc twice). To snapshot your result, try adding the `.snapshot()` to your query, like:

`var cursor = db.myCollection.find({country:'uk'}).snapshot();`

I never tested that, so please confirm if this approach wathever worked or not.